# How I can get strings of consecutive binary numbers?

Tags: haskell

How can I put in `iterate` function like this: `showIntAtBase a intToDigit b ""`? I tried to use composition (`showIntAtBase a intToDigit (\x -> iterate (+1) 0) ""`), but it's absolutely incorrect.

For example, I'm trying to generate strings of binary numbers from decimal numbers in infinite list:
`take 7 $ myFunc => ["0", "01", "10", "11", "100", "101", "110"]`

Comment: What are the types of these functions?  What are you trying to actually do?  Maybe an example input with the expected output?

Comment: @bheklilr I added example, I hope it's more clearly now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So based on your example, you want to perform the following steps:

1. Start at `n = "0"`
2. Convert `n` to an `Int`
3. Add `1` to `nInt`
4. Convert `nInt` to a base 2 `String`
5. Go to step 2.

This is indeed a great application for the `iterate` function; however it looks like you've got your function composition and order all messed up.  I'm going to assume you have the following functions defined:

```
-- Converts `n` to base `base` as a String
showIntAtBase :: Int -> Int -> String
showIntAtBase base n = undefined

-- Converts the String `s` to an `Int` assuming its in base `base`
readIntBase :: Int -> String -> Int
readIntBase base s = undefined
```

Such that

```
showIntAtBase b . readIntBase b === id
-- and
readIntBase b . showIntAtBase b === id
```

It's up to you to prove that these functions are inverses of each other and work properly.

I would then write a function that does steps 2 through 4 for me

```
incrBase2 :: String -> String
incrBase2 s = showIntAtBase 2 $ (\x -> x + 1) $ readIntBase 2 s
```

Or, you could write it more simply as

```
incrBase2 = showIntAtBase 2 . (+1) . readIntBase 2
```

Now you can use `iterate` on `incrBase2`:

```
allBinary :: [String]
allBinary = iterate incrBase2 "0"
```

Comment: @augustss I never said it was the best solution, I was trying to make it similar to what OP already had. My solution would just be too map `showIntAtBase 2` to `[0..]` and just not mess with iterating. However, the question was about using iterate with the functions already defined, so I answered it that way.

Answer (score 1):

Except `"0"`, all numbers start with `1`. So let's only consider what happens to the tails of the binary numbers starting with `1`:

```
""    -- 1
"0"   -- 10
"1"   -- 11
"00"  -- 100
"01"  -- 101
"10"  -- 110
"11"  -- 111
```

etc.

What we see here, is a pattern that first we append `0` to the head of the result of the previous iteration, then we append `1` in the same manner.

```
ts = concat $ iterate (\xss -> [h:xs | h <-['0','1'], xs <- xss]) [[]]
```

produces those tails.

Just add `"0"` at the beginning of the list, and append `1` to the list of tails:

```
bins = "0" : map ('1':) ts where
   ts = concat $ iterate (liftM2 (:) "01"]) [[]]
```

Comment: Incidentally, another interesting way to write `ts` is `[0..] >>= (\`replicateM\` "01")`. That is, "for each integer N, starting with 0, choose from ['0', '1'] N times, and concat it together".

Comment: @amalloy ooh, that's neat!